# Auto Logging JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetImagePaths() {
        GetImagePathsMethod();
    }
    function autoLogin()
    {
        document.loginForm.action = "xxxxx";
        document.loginForm.submit();
    }
</script>
body onload="autoLogin()">
    <div class="minHeightBody">
        <div style="overflow:hidden;">
            <div style="width:2000px !important;overflow:hidden;">
                <div class="overridepanelClass addBorderAndWidth" style="float:left;">
                    <div id="slider" class="pics">
                        <!--Initial Image that needs to be loaded-->
                        <img id="image" style="width: 100%; height: 900px;" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/quote3.jpg")">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="overridepanelClass addBorderAndWidth" style="float:left;padding-left:5px;">
                    <div id="displaySite" class="panel2Properities">
                        <!--Initial Site that needs to be loaded-->
                        <iframe src="XXXXX" height=900 width=2900></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form name="loginForm" id="login" target="frame" method="post">
                    <input name="username" type="hidden" value="xxxx">
                    <input name="password" type="hidden" value="xxx">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to auto login using the above script and nothing happens..is there a different way of doing it if I use iframes or am i completely doing something wrong

Comment: Your HTML is broken (`body` should be `<body`) and you should access your form using `document.getElementById('login')`. Grabbing forms by name is wonky at best.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply, broken body tag was a typo. I actually replaced it with document.getElementById('login') but didnt work

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form to the `iframe` with `src=xxxxx`?

Comment: yes will I am trying to submit the form within the iframe src

Answer (score 0):

document.loginForm.action = "xxxxx"; should reference the id of the form